# I am unable to connect to the extension marketplace of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found one solution,  download latest version from  [VSCode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). I tried same but still facing this issue.
i want to add React Native extension.

I am unable to access this [URL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com) because of the Proxy.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bypass the url from proxy.
Open proxy settings (run command - inetcpl.cpl)
Go to connection tab, now in your proxy add that url 
If it works then ok . Else you have to contact network team or need to do some firewall settings

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!
Any alternative way  to solve this issue?

Comment: If the first solution haven't work. Then you can try with DNS entry in network for that URL. (Shortcut run command - drivers) . But I strongly recommend you to get some help from Newark team. Because most of the companies blocks URL with https.

Comment: yes i have same firewall issue,
actually i am looking for the other ways no problem thanks.

Comment: I Struggled with same kind of synario. Sometimes I managed with proxy bypass and DNS Entry with server IPs. But If firewall completely blocks required sites then we can't do anything at application level. Network or support team have to play there role in such kind of situation.

Answer (score 21):

I'm using VSCodium On Archlinux and had the same problem. I installed `vscodium-bin-marketplace` to make it work. There's also a package named `code-marketplace` for Code OSS.

Comment: How can i install `code-marketplace` in manjaro? i try `sudo pacman -S code-marketplace`. but it does not work.

Comment: You can easily install it through "yay", Yay is an AUR helper. Follow this link to see how to install it: https://github.com/Jguer/yay

Comment: Thanks, dude. if fix it via [this post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/code-oss-marketplace/73870/9) in the manjaro forum

Comment: @KasirBarati You can use [pamac](https://itsfoss.com/install-remove-software-manjaro/)

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution that works for me.

Stop VSCode.

Open ~/.vscode/argv.json if you're using VSCode

Open ~/.vscode-oss/argv.json if you're using VSCodium

Then add

```
// Browser Code Loading.
"enable-browser-code-loading": false
```

Don't forget to add a comma to the previous entry, since this is a JSON file (but you knew that already, right?).

Comment: Context: [vscodium github issue](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/746#issuecomment-881049046), [archlinux bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/71525)

Answer (score 9):

This just worked for me:

Add the proxy server to VS Code settings.json (open it in VSCode command line)
[image]

Add keys "http.proxy" and "https.proxy" with values of your Proxy Server URL, for example:

settings.json:

```
{
  ...
  "http.proxy": "http://my-http-proxy-server.com:123",
  "https.proxy": "https://my-https-proxy-server.com:124"
}
```

Comment: this solution worked for me if you behind the proxy in company like me.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting my .vscode  (hidden folder) worked for me.

C:\Users\USERNAME.vscode

Other alternative could be uninstalling vscode and deleting the whole folder at

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this solution for **linux operating systems**:

in file `~/.vscode-oss/argv.json`
add this line: `"enable-browser-code-loading": false`

Answer (score 1):

1. Unistall **vscode** from `unins000.exe` `C:\Users\{username-PC}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`
2. Delete `C:\Users\{username-PC}\AppData\Roaming\Code`
3. Delete `C:\Users\{username-PC}\.vscode`
4. Restart

Answer (score 1):

I went to **Toggle Developer Tools**. As described in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81115#issuecomment-533446002). Saw that `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` error is there.

I had a proxy server added to the network settings. (Which was working fine for other purposes) I had to remove the proxy server in order to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

1.Unistall vscode from `unins000.exe` `C:\Users\{username-PC}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft` VS Code

2.Delete `C:\Users\{username-PC}\AppData\Roaming\Code`

3.Delete `C:\Users\{username-PC}\.vscode`

4.Restart

5.Reset your windows firewall

6.Restart and install Vscode

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: in extensions search box, wrote @color (I'm guessing searching for anything will do) and extensions tab populated with results. Never saw the error again.

Answer (score 1):

If no option works above. You can install the extension through the Vsix file.You can download it from this site.
[Vsix File Free Download](https://www.vsixhub.com/vsix/1950/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux you can install code-marketplace using your package manager which in my case it's `pamac`.

Just like this:

```
pamac build code-marketplace
```

**This fixed my problem loading extensions in vscode.**

Answer (score 0):

I am using kaspersky antivirus, disable it for a while, and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

goto your pc settings and look for proxy

turn it all off

that worked for me

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29824571)

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled vscode downloaded it again and it works fine now for me you can try out this once

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. (for vscode)

- Open setting.json in vscode

  - Ctrl+Shift+p
  - search "setting.json"
- then delete "http.proxy" line

Answer (score -1):

When you look at the ip-traffic what it tries to do, it starts with DNS-query with A-record (good) and also with AAAA-record (not so good if you don't have proper v6 routing in place).

Application should have built-in code to try AAAA-record connections and if they fail, it should automatically fall back to v4-connections and routing. Now it fails to do so and just gives an error that it failed to connect marketplace. Well, you just didn't try hard enough, did you?

For Linux systems, you disable your host's v6 protocol with:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and you might want to write them into /etc/sysctl.conf file as well.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I did it using the world's best editor Vim! :)

You need to restart the application before marketplace starts working.