# VS Code cannot connect to the extensions marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, miniconda

I've started a job at a company and they gave us all brand new laptops.
I installed miniconda (4.9.2) and vscode (1.56.2) on mine, but I have an error message in vscode extensions tab that says:

> We cannot connect to the extensions marketplace at this time, please
> try again later

But two of my colleagues that have the exact same laptop configuration and connection have no trouble accessing the extensions, though they did not take any particular action to access it.

I tried vs code insiders with no success.
Anyone has any idea?

EDIT: when I access the console of vscode development's tools, I see this error: "net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES"

Comment: See if [this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247646/i-am-unable-to-connect-to-the-extension-marketplace-of-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I tried several of the things on your link but it did not do the trick.
`Open proxy settings (run command - inetcpl.cpl) Go to connection tab, now in your proxy add that url ` i could not o this one as I don't see the proxy here
I couldn't either enter the proxy in vscode json because I don't have the details...

Comment: and I tried several times to uninstall vscode, including deleting the .vscode folder